# Using LayoutLMv2 from HuggingFace Transformers to get information as text

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use LayoutLMv2 to extract information from some invoice pictures.
So far, and based on what is [on this documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/layoutlmv2#transformers.LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering), I've run the following:

```
from transformers import LayoutLMv2Processor, LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering

 from PIL import Image

 import torch

 processor = LayoutLMv2Processor.from_pretrained("microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased")

model = LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased")

image = Image.open("name_of_your_document - can be a png file, pdf, etc.").convert("RGB")

question = "what's his name?"

encoding = processor(image, question, return_tensors="pt")

start_positions = torch.tensor([1])

end_positions = torch.tensor([3])

outputs = model(**encoding, start_positions=start_positions, 
end_positions=end_positions)

loss = outputs.loss 

start_scores = outputs.start_logits

end_scores = outputs.end_logits
```

However, I'm not exactly sure, how from this we can extract the characters, and not just a visual box... For a visual box, there are a few gradio apps [here](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased) on the spaces links. However, all the examples draw boxes on the picture, and I want to extract the answer as text.